# "JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property" - react-native-avataaars

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-package

I'm trying to use a package [react-native-avataaars](https://github.com/tom555my/react-native-avataaars/tree/dependabot/npm_and_yarn/lodash-4.17.21) to allow users to create custom avatars but this package is causing errors. I followed the example but the code is underlined in red with an error `JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property. 'Avatar' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'Avatar' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'Avatar' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.`

When I try to run the app, ignoring the error, it cannot open. Instead the bundler gives errors:

```
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextEncoder
Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS from /Users/user/Desktop/APP/node_modules/react-native/index.js: 

None of these files exist:
  15 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
  16 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
> 17 | import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';
     |                                   ^
  18 | import typeof DrawerLayoutAndroid from './Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid';
  19 | import typeof FlatList from './Libraries/Lists/FlatList';
  20 | import typeof Image from './Libraries/Image/Image';
```

and

```
"main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder.
Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and
'AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.
```

I've tried removing `node_modules` and using `npm install`, as well as running `npm start --reset-cache` and `npm start -c` but nothing worked. There is no issue that mentions these errors on GitHub for the package, open or closed. I'm lost after over an hour of looking for solutions. I confirmed this package/component is the issue because when I remove the usage in my screen everything works fine. For now, I'll move on without using the package but I would really like to add this feature. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Globe., Are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes, I am using Typescript @Gavara.Suneel

Comment: I think the issue is due to the typescript resolutions. A similar issue is there in another library as well and this should be the probable fix. https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/1595#issuecomment-1121032047

Comment: Ok, so I just stripped the package down and used the 2 main files so there aren't any issues with versions. Now the error in the code is gone but all errors still show when the app opens. The errors are the same as in the original question. The biggest one is that "main" has not been registered which seems to be caused by the DatePickerIOS module.

Answer (score 0):

So there were two issues, both related to the package. Here are my fixes.

The first issue was typescript. The workaround was to download the package locally and just keep the files that mattered. Remove the `node_modules` and `package.json` (etc...). Then install the missing dependencies to the root project so there won't be issues with versions.

The second issue is that the package uses `TextDecoder` which I did not have. Fix:

1. `npm install text-encoding`
2. `npm install big-integer`
3. Remove `node_modules`
4. `npm install`
5. Go to `node_modules -> react-native -> Libraries -> LogBox -> LogBox.js`
6. Add the following code

```js
   const TextEncodingPolyfill = require('text-encoding');
   const BigInt = require('big-integer')
   Object.assign(global, {
     TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
     TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
     BigInt: BigInt,
   });
```

7. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`